# Is color scheme file cached?

Tags: caching, sublimetext3, color-scheme

I'm using `IDLE` color scheme for Sublime 3, but it did not have `diff` syntax highglight. SO I found one that I could use it. I added it using `PackageResourceViewer`. After adding additional content into scheme, I noticed diff syntax working. But I did not like that insertion was colored blue and diff header was green.

So I swapped colors between diff `header` and `insertion`. But it had no effect. Header was still green and insertion was still blue. It looks like file is cached somewhere, because I could even delete `diff` highlight declaration and it would still show me highlights.

My current scheme (with swapped colors) is this:

```
   <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>diff.header</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.diff, meta.diff.header</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#3333FF</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>diff.deleted</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>markup.deleted</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#DD5555</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>diff.inserted</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>markup.inserted</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#009933</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>diff.changed</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>markup.changed</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#E6DB74</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Note. Even if I close sublime, open with `PRV`, I can see that in file my changes persist, but actual syntax is still showed from initial `copy/paste`.

Comment: You are right. It automatically switches to SublimeLinter color scheme `IDLE (SL)`. Though after switching back to default `IDLE`, it started showing changes. Thanks for good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some packages quite often decide to make tweaks to the color scheme, and thus create a new color scheme so as to not mess with the original - then they set your active color scheme to their tweaked copy. Therefore, although ST doesn't cache the color scheme - it will look as though it does.

To check, you can see the output from `view.settings().get('color_scheme')` <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the ST console (View menu -> Show Console) - most often the packages that do this name their copy of the color scheme as the original with `(package name)` appended to the end.

Or check the main User preferences file. Just set it back to your color scheme, and the package will probably do the same thing again but at least it should include your changes this time.

Comment: Yes it does change back to `IDLE (SL)` after I try to change to default one, but changes are applied. So thats good for me.