# Customise colour scheme Sublime Text 3.0 build 3143

Tags: sublimetext3

I used to be able to use Package Resource Viewer to customise colours of ST's themes (my favourite: Eiffel), but after the new update, I can edit the colour code but nothing changes.

Do you know how?

Here's what I did:
Use PackageResourceViewer to open Eiffel.thmTheme file and edit the colour codes in there.

```
<dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Comment</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>comment</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>fontStyle</key>
                <string>italic</string>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>red</string> <!-- comment colour -->
                <key>background</key>
                <string>yellow</string> <!-- comment background colour -->
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

**Update:**
This is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437309/is-color-scheme-file-cached) question, because I'm asking about a method to edit colours in the current version of Sublime. The other question is about how to change colours of header and intersection.

Comment: No, it's totally not.

Comment: I'm using Eiffel. And the colours were what I customised before I upgraded Sublime. After running the update today, I chose Eiffel and the colours are now default colours of the colour scheme. I used the same method as described above but it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you should copy your custom color packages to `C:/Users/**your username**/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages`
(assuming your windows drive letter is C:)

- or

You can launch Sublime, click Preferences - Browse Packages, the explorer window pops up. Next, you click one folder up, and see four folders, one of them should be 'Installed packages'. This is the folder you need to fill with your color scheme packages.

Just upgraded and found out what to do. It works now.

Comment: thank you for your reply. It looks like you're talking about installing a custom colour package (like Boxy). I'm asking about how to edit the colour of 1 of the default colour schemes. Unless, I totally misunderstand your reply.

Comment: Try to use the file 'Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package' and move it to a new location.

Tip: you can rename 'Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package' to 'Color Scheme - Default.zip', unzip it, pull out any .tmtheme, edit it here http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com and then use it, zipped back and renamed to .sublime-package again. Then see my 1st answer.

Comment: upd: I moved Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package to C:/Users/**your username**/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages and it works fine. (check it here: http://prntscr.com/gkxdo4 )